# Cannot disable spring-data-mongodb-reactive autoconfiguration in spring-boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

No matter what I try, I cannot disable auto-configuration of spring-data-mongodb-reactive.

**Properties**

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: "mongodb://user:pw@some-ip.amazonaws.com:27017/my-db"
      repositories:
        type: reactive
      authentication-database: admin
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
interface IMembersRepository: ReactiveMongoRepository<Member, String> {}
```

**MongoConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackages = ["com.my.package.repository"])
class MongoConfig : AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration() {

    override fun reactiveMongoClient(): MongoClient = mongoClient()

    override fun getDatabaseName(): String = "my-db"

    @Bean()
    fun mongoClient() = MongoClients.create()

    @Bean()
    override fun reactiveMongoTemplate() = ReactiveMongoTemplate(mongoClient(), databaseName)
}
```

**AppConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
@ComponentScan("com.my.package")
class AppConfig: WebFluxConfigurer {
    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
        registry.addMapping("api/**")
    }
}
```

**SpringBootApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [
    MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration::class,
    MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration::class,
    MongoReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration::class,
    MongoAutoConfiguration::class,
    MongoDataAutoConfiguration::class,
    MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration::class,
    EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration::class
])
class AstridServerApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<AstridServerApplication>(*args)
}
```

As you can see, I even went as far as disabling all available MongoDB auto-configs, and Boot still tries to establish connection to a local instance, which I do not have. But I did also try different combinations.

```
[localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$OpenCompletionHandler.failed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:158) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:186) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:298) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl$ConnectTask.failed(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:308) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:389) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The remote computer refused the network connection
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Iocp.translateErrorToIOException(Iocp.java:299) ~[na:na]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

The client is connecting to the default address. I would focus on understanding why your config file isn't taking effect rather than on "disabling auto-configuration". The behavior you are seeing is consistent with the client not receiving any external configuration and using its built-in defaults.

Comment: I do end up with connection to the external DB. But I also end up with a failed local connection because I have no local DB. I do not want this behavior, just external connection.

Answer (score 0):

In the spring-autoconfigure-metadata.properties I found a list of fields you can specify.

Since I needed to override the code in AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration (there are other classes if you are not using reactive)

I just extended the class and pointed to it like this
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.         MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration="mypackage.MyCustomAbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration"

No need to exclude anything (which wasn't really possible)